# Problem running a very simple Python program

Tags: python, ide, python-idle

Why is my program giving me an error here?

```
import random

TheNumber = random.randrange(1,200,1)
NotGuessed = True
Tries = 0

GuessedNumber = int(input("Take a guess at the magic number!: "))                 

while NotGuessed == True:
    if GuessedNumber < TheNumber:
        print("Your guess is a bit too low.")
        Tries = Tries + 1
        GuessedNumber = int(input("Take another guess at the magic number!: "))

    if GuessedNumber > TheNumber:
        print("Your guess is a bit too high!")
        Tries = Tries + 1
        GuessedNumber = int(input("Take another guess at the magic number!: "))

    if GuessedNumber == TheNumber:
        print("You've guess the number, and it only took you " + string(Tries) + "!")
```

The error is on the last line. What can I do?

Edit:

Also, why can;t I use Tries++ here in Python? Isn't there an autoincrement code?

Edit 2: Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sergio/Desktop/GuessingGame.py", line 21, in <module>
    print("You've guess the number, and it only took you " + string(Tries) + "!")
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

Comment: Most importantly, your casting of a variable to string is unnecessary in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's `str`, not `string`. but your infinite loop is a bigger problem. auto-increment is written like this:

```
Tries += 1
```

General comment: you could improve your code slightly:

```
the_number = random.randrange(1,200,1)
tries = 1

guessed_number = int(input("Take a guess at the magic number!: ")) 
while True:
    if guessed_number < the_number:
        print("Your guess is a bit too low.")

    if guessed_number > the_number:
        print("Your guess is a bit too high!")

    if guessed_number == the_number:
        break
    else:
        guessed_number = int(input("Take another guess at the magic number!: "))
        tries += 1

print("You've guessed the number, and it only took you %d tries!" % tries)
```

Comment: I fixed it with your code, and my computer shot itself in the motherboard. Thanks a lot SO.

Comment: Did you fix the infinite loop before the shooting?

Comment: I meant that infinite loop made my computer kill itself xD

Answer (score 3):

In your last line, replace `string` with `str` -- that should take care of the error python is complaining about, at least.